# What are different clients available in java for elastic search?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

What are different clients available in java as well as in spring MVC/spring Boot for elastic search?
What's difference between them and advantage of each one and which one is better to use with spring boot for querying and source filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [official java client JHLRC](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html) which can be easily integrate with any java based system and has integration with spring data.

It can also very easily integrate with spring boot and check [query part](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/_search_apis.html) and [document apis for source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-supported-apis.html)

for spring-data please refer their [various elasticsearch clients section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients)

Comment: Thanks a lot @opster-elasticsearch-ninja. I am new to elastic search, could you please tell me what is the difference between elasticsearchtemplate and elasticsearchresttemplate? which one to use in springboot project and how is it different from JHLRC?

Comment: Thanks @opster-elasticsearch-ninja. would you be kind enough to share the code snippet, this is the question I posted earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625939/how-to-load-particular-field-of-document-on-demand-lazy-loading-of-field-in-el?

Comment: @implosivesilence lazy loading as mentioned might not be possible, but if you want normal one I can provide code for that

Comment: Thanks @opster-elasticsearch-ninja. I will do it and also would you be kind enough to answer new question posted by me :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62695368/how-to-do-source-filtering-in-elasticsearch-in-spring-boot-project

Comment: sure will do in a while, thanks for posting a new answer

Comment: Hi @opster-elasticsearch-ninja.I have posted a separate question, would you be kind enough to answer it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771342/get-all-non-full-fields-in-elasticsearchrepositorys-findall-method-in-spring-da

Comment: @implosivesilence I dont have a spring data project setup, let me know if you are OK with just JHLRC (java high level client)code ?

Comment: Hi @opster-elasticsearch-ninja.the requirement is spring specific. Thanks.

Comment: @implosivesilence can you share your git repo with readme so that its easy for me to repro issue