# How to do source filtering in ElasticSearch in spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

how to make Elastic search query return only particular fields in spring boot project using spring-data-elasticsearch? we are using most recent versions of spring boot and elastic search.
Which template to use elasticsearchtemplate or elasticsearchresttemplate and how both of them are different from java high level rest client?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `ElasticsearchOperations` interface (which `ElasticsearchTemplate` and `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` implement), the Query interface that is used to define the query to execute has a method addSourceFilter where you can add a FetchSourceFilter which defines the fields to be retrieved from Elasticsearch, the other fields will be null.

Comment: Thnaks p-j-meisch . I have tried that but I am getting an error, would you be kind enough to answer my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699759/how-to-return-single-object-using-nativesearchquerybuilder-of-elasticsearch-in-s