# How to return single object using NativeSearchQueryBuilder of ElasticSearch in Spring Project?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using NativeSearchQueryBuilder to form the Query as follows:

```
 String[] includeFields = new String[]{"idDl", "clientName"};
 String[] excludeFields = new String[]{"Address"};
 Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(matchQuery("idDl", idDl))
                .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(includeFields, excludeFields))
                 .build();
return elasticsearchRestTemplate.queryForObject((StringQuery) searchQuery, User.class);
```

I want to return single object without the certain fields and this is the Stack-trace of the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQuery cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.StringQuery
at com.user.services.UserQueryServiceImpl.getUserById(UserQueryServiceImpl.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
at com.User.controllers.UserController.getFilteredUserById(UserController.java:100) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `queryForObject` is deprecated, you should use `searchOne()`. As for your error:

You create a `NativeSearchQuery`, assigne it to the variable `searchQuery` which is of type `Query`; that's alright.
But why do you try to cast this to a `StringQuery`?

`NativeSearchQuery` and `StringQuery` both implement `Query`, so just pass your query instance:

```
return elasticsearchRestTemplate.queryForObject(searchQuery, User.class)
```

**Edit for Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.x:**

You should use

```
<T> List<T> queryForList(SearchQuery query, Class<T> clazz);
```

as in that version there was still the `SearchQuery` interface that `NativeSearchQuery`implements. From the returned list, check if it contains any elements and then use the first one.

Comment: Thanks @p-j-meisch. i changed my searchQuery variable from Query to SearchQuery. But if I do not cast it, I am getting error as "Cannot resolve Method queryForObject(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Query" and IDE is suggesting to cast it to either of StringQuery, GetQuery and CriteriaQuery. same worked for queryForList if i changed my searchQuery variable from Query to SearchQuery.

Comment: we are not able to find the method elasticsearchRestTemplate.searchOne(), we're using spring-data-elasticsearch 3.2.6.RELEASE

Comment: you didn't mention which version you use. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @p-j-meisch.

Comment: I have posted separate question for it, Hi, @p-j-meisch .I have posted separate question regarding it, would you be kind enough to answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771342/get-all-non-full-fields-in-elasticsearchrepositorys-findall-method-in-spring-da